# Switch Derived class of a shared pointer to base class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I am currently trying to switch the type of a derived class stored in a shared pointer to base class.
The problem is that the Derived class inherit from the Base class and is also templated as follow:

Base class:

```
#define PRINT(s) std::cout << s << std::endl

class Base {
public:
    Base() : m_a(1) {}
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void print() { PRINT("BASE"); }

    int m_a;
};
```

The derived class depend on an enumeration template:

```
enum eType { e0, e1 };

template<eType et>
class Derived : public Base { };

template<>
class Derived<e0> : public Base {
public:
    Derived() { this->m_a = e0; }
    void print() { PRINT("Derived e0, m_a value: " << e0 ); }
};

template<>
class Derived<e1> : public Base {
public:
    Derived() { this->m_a = e1; }
    void print() { PRINT("Derived e1, m_a value: " << e1 ); }
};
```

My objective is to have a shared pointer to the Base class so it would be possible to switch from the 2 derived classes as follow:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> sp_00 = std::make_shared<Derived<e0>> ();

    std::shared_ptr<Base> sp_01 = sp_00;
    sp_01->print();

    std::shared_ptr<Base> sp_10 = std::make_shared<Derived<e1>> ();

    *sp_01 = *sp_10;

    sp_01->print();
    sp_10->print();
}
```

The only problem as on the line `*sp_01 = *sp_10;` I expect that the pointer to base class switch from the derived type `Derived<e0>` to the derived type `Derived<e1>`. However in my example I get a different result for the line `sp_01->print();` and the line `sp_10->print();` indicating that `sp_01` stays as a `Derived<e0>` type.

I want to avoid `sp_01 = sp_10;` because it will change the pointer. In the above example, it would lead to `sp_00 != sp_01` and I want both `sp_00` and `sp_01` to share the same object.

I tried to replace the template derived class by a non template derived class as follow:

```
class Derived_e0 : public Base {
public:
    Derived() { this->m_a = e0; }
    void print() { PRINT("Derived e0, m_a value: " << e0 ); }
};
class Derived_e1 : public Base {
public:
    Derived() { this->m_a = e1; }
    void print() { PRINT("Derived e1, m_a value: " << e1 ); }
};
```

and the following code give the same result as the one with template.

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> sp_00 = std::make_shared<Derived_e0> ();

    std::shared_ptr<Base> sp_01 = sp_00;
    sp_01->print();

    std::shared_ptr<Base> sp_10 = std::make_shared<Derived_e1> ();

    *sp_01 = *sp_10;

    sp_01->print();
    sp_10->print();
}
```

So my question is, how to switch the derived object pointed by a shared pointer without changing the shared_ptr itself (which is used in other part of the program ?)

Thanks, if you need any more information, please let me know

Comment: You cannot change the "polymorphic type" of `sp_01` without reassigning `sp_01`. How could you do that if `Derived<e0>` and `Derived<e1>` did not have the same size? Your design (or what you are trying to do with) is probably flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the runtime type of `sp_01` without re-assigning it because you cannot assign `Derived<e1>` to `Derived<e0>` (think of what would happen if these do not have the same size - you have allocated enough size for a `Derived<e0>`, not for a `Derived<e1>`!).

In my opinion, your design (or what you are trying to do with it) is flawed somewhere. However, if you really want to keep a "link" between `sp_00` and `sp_01`, you probably need another "level" of pointer:

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Base> *psp_01;

    std::shared_ptr<Base> sp_00 = std::make_shared<Derived<e0>> ();
    psp_01 = &sp_00;

    (*psp_01)->print();

    std::shared_ptr<Base> sp_10 = std::make_shared<Derived<e1>> ();
    psp_01 = &sp_10;

    (*psp_01)->print();
    sp_10->print();
}
```

But again, I would analyze my design twice before using this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works with the expected behavior. I guess you are right about the design and I will try to change it.
If I have `sp_00`, `sp_01` and other shared_ptr sharing the same Derived class, would it be possible to have a function that call all those instance and re-assign them to the same shared_ptr ?
It would be possible with a global vector but I guess it is a bad pratice ^^

Comment: @SchneiderLoïc No, assigning `*sp_00` to `*sp_01` will actually call `operator=(Base const&)` of `Base`, which will reassign the `Base` part of `sp_01` to `sp_00` (typically, in your case, `m_a` will be reassign, but not something that would only be in `Derived<e0>` or `Derived<e1>`).

Comment: @SchneiderLoïc See http://rextester.com/TJEAV61599, when reassigning `*pxa = *pxb`, only the `x_` of `X` is re-assigned, the `y_` attribute stay to `1` even though `Y<1>` and `Y<2>` are similar (but they are not the same class!). Trying to cast `pxa` to a `Y<2>*` will even fail in this case - The runtime type did not change with the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamic_cast the raw pointer; something like

```
Derived* t = dymanic_cast<Derived*>(sp_00.get())
```

And you'll get NULL if it can't be cast, or a valid pointer if it can.  That said, this requires RTTI to be built in, which will make your binary bigger, and needing to do this at all is a sign that your design isn't right.